# Multiplying the numbers of a String

Tags: c

I want to multiply the numbers in a given string which has one or more spaces.

**Example:**

> If i input `52 26 23`
>   the output should be `31096`.

I've written this code but its not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[30];
    int i, num = 0, v = 1;
    gets(input);

    for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(input[i] == 32)
        {
            v = v * num;
            if(input[i+1] != 32)
            {
                num = 0;
                continue;
                }
            }
            num = (num * 10) + (input[i] - 48);
    }

    printf("%d",v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it for academic purpose or are you able to use predefined functions ?

Comment: When do you think the inner `if` block gets executed? Use a debugger or put `printf` statements and check.

Comment: its for academic purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[30];
    char *token;
    long int mul = 1;
    gets(str);
    token  = strtok(str, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        mul = mul * atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("%ld",mul);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Working with one space

Comment: Thanks its working.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in your nested if statement.  Once it enters the first if statement, that means `input[i]==32`, therefore it can never enter the next if statement where `input[i]!=32`.

I also have some suggestions for improving readability.  Instead of using numbers to represent the characters, use the character literals themselves!

Another thing, you only have space for 30 characters in your `input` buffer.  If a user attempts to enter more than this, you will have a buffer overflow.

Lastly, if the user puts more than one space between numbers, the output will become 0.  That may be something you may or may not want to handle.

**Edit:** Before, the call to `gets` was only grabbing characters up to the first whitespace character.  I've fixed this issue with a format string in a call to `scanf` instead.  Buffer overflow problem still applies.  Also, it was not multiplying with the last parsed integer, so I added code for that after the loop.  Another note, this will only work for non-negative integers, if that's something you weren't aware of initially.  The code just assumes the input is nice.

**Edit 2:** support for input with any number of spaces before, between, or after inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char input[30];
  int i, num = 0, v = 1;

  scanf("%[^\n]s", input);

  // skip leading spaces
  for(i = 0; input[i] == ' '; i++);

  // parse remaining input
  while(input[i] != '\0') {
    if(input[i] == ' ') {
      v *= num;
      num = 0;
      // skip subsequent spaces
      while(input[++i] == ' ');
      continue;
    }

    num *= 10;
    num += input[i] - '0';
    i++;
  }

  // ignore trailing spaces
  if(input[i - 1] != ' ') {
    // get last parsed integer
    v *= num;
  }

  printf("%i\n", v);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compute the expected result for the given input.

Comment: Thanks, made changes!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It seems as sombody voted *all* down. I don't know who but I have a strong guess ;-)

Comment: I have not downvote. But Your code does not meet "string which has one or more spaces"'s requirement. Also `"%[^\n]s"` : `s` is superfluous.

Comment: See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/LDUkIR)