# How can I multiply numbers in a string by grouping them according to intervals?

Tags: c, string

I want to get a result of dividing a string of numbers by a specific interval and multiplying it. I know how to change one character into a number.

Here's the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "123456";
    int a, b, c;
    a = str[0] - '0';
    b = 23; // desired to be changed. str[1] ~ str[2]
    c = 456; // desired to be changed. str[3] ~ str[5]
    printf("%c * %c%c * %c%c%c = %d", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], a * b * c);
}
```

I designated the index interval to be divided as 0, 1 to 2, 3 to 5.
I didn't know how to convert characters into numbers, so I stored values directly for the variables.

Here's the output: `1 * 23 * 456 = 10488`

Here's the desired result:

1. In str, change the number corresponding to index 0 to int type.
2. In str, change the number corresponding to index 1 to 2 to int type.
3. In str, change the number corresponding to index 3 to 5 to int type.
4. Multiply the changed numbers.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988383/multiplying-the-numbers-of-a-string) is related. However, I am curious about how the user intentionally divides and multiplies the sections rather than dividing them according to spaces.

Comment: Please rephrase _"I am curious about how the user arbitrarily divides and multiplies the sections rather than dividing them according to spaces."_ to explicitly describe what you need to know.

Comment: How do you know which digits belong to what number? Please [edit] your question and provide that requirement. If you don't know it, how can your program know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to convert two digit string into number you need to multiple first digit by 10 and add second digit, the same for 3 digit, something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

// converts number stored between start/end indexes into integer
int parse(char* str, int start, int end) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=start; i<=end; i++) {
        result = result*10 + (str[i] - '0');
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "123456";
    int a, b, c;
    a = parse(str, 0, 0);
    b = parse(str, 1, 2);
    c = parse(str, 3, 5);
    printf("%d * %d * %d = %d", a, b, c, a * b * c);
}
```

Comment: @ryyker I suppose question is clear, how to extract numbers from string according to their indexes

Answer (score 0):

> *"I didn't know how to convert characters into numbers"*

Based on your example algorithm enumerated in steps `1`, `2`, `3` & `4`, without including any user input instructions, here is an implementation that extracts the 3 integers from the source string by using string parsing, copying and string to number conversion.

```
int main(void)
{   
    char str[] = "123456";
    char num1[10]={0};//note {0} initializes all memory locations in buffer to NULL
    char num2[10]={0};
    char num3[10]={0};
    int n1, n2, n3;
    char *tmp;
    
    //1. In str, change the number corresponding to index 0 to int type
    strncpy(num1, str, 1);
    n1 = atoi(num1);
    //2. In str, change the number corresponding to index 1 to 2 to int type.
    tmp = strchr(str, '2');
    strncpy(num2, tmp, 2);
    n2 = atoi(num2);
    //3. In str, change the number corresponding to index 3 to 5 to int type.
    tmp = strchr(str, '4');
    strncpy(num3, tmp, 3);
    n3 = atoi(num3);

    //4. Multiply the changed numbers.
    int result = n1*n2*n3;
    printf("%d", result);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs;

```
10488
```